# What does it mean if a probability $p$ is bounded by $poly(n)$?

Tags: probability, algorithms, notation

So I am supposed to give a randomized algorithm that solves a problem with probability

$$q > p \ge {1 \over poly(n)}.$$

I assume that $poly(n)$ means something like $O(n^k)$, but what kind of values does $1/poly(n)$ take then?

Comment: I suppose you should be able to exhibit a polynomial $f(x)$ such that $p\cdot f(n)\ge 1$ holds for all $n$ (and I assume that your $p=p(n)$ depends on $n$).

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to give an algorithm such that *there exists* a polynomial function $f$ such that $p(n)\ge 1/f(n)$ for all $n$?